# Class path Error

Tags: java

Some Snippet of my code is shown as below;

```
    String log4jConfigPath = FileUtil.getFilePathFromClasspath("log4j.properties");
    if (null != log4jConfigPath) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(log4jConfigPath);
    } else {
        logger.warn("log4j.properties not found on classpath!");
    }
    Config config = Config.getConfig("crawler.properties");
    String mode = config.getString("crawler.mode").toLowerCase();
```

I m getting an error for both the files "log4j.properties" and "crawler.properties" not found in class path..i have this files residing in folders in my projects..Can someone please tell me how to add this files to class path compiler looks for both this properties files.

Thanks;

Comment: What folders are these files in? They should be in the default package from the looks of things.

Comment: hi I moved all the file to default package....Its not showing an error now...thnks

Answer (score 0):

The folder, that contains `log4j.properties` has to be added to the classpath, either relative to your current working directory or absolute:

```
/
+-project
  +-src
  | +-com
  |   +-example
  |    +-Hello
  +-resource
   +-log4j.properties
```

now, if you current directory is `/project`, then you have to run your app with

```
java -cp src;resource com.example.Hello                       # relative paths
java -cp /project/src;/project/resource com.example.Hello     # absolute paths
```